# How to monitor HTTP network traffic in a Windows Phone in runtime?

Tags: windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8, monitoring, analytics

I would like to log while my Windows Phone 7/8 App runs all the HTTP requests/responses.

Is this possible in runtime? And how? Any classes/service I can register and notified with events with detailed information?

I would like to get general analysis monitoring information other than HTTP only like the Windows Phone Analysis tool provides. Any idea how?

I want to use the framework only and no 3rd party tools or SDK.

Comment: currently there is not such class/service in WP SDK. You can implement you own `Analytic tool` and add it to your app when it does request. Any cons about `Google` or `Flurry` analytic?

Comment: "You can implement you own Analytic tool"...What exactly do you mean? No cons to the tools, but I would like to learn how this is achieved.

Comment: I can't just track my own methods inside an app with like calling a method to log details. I want this to happen everytime I use this library to track applications or other libraries for HTTP monitoring.